# Pilot light keeps going out

Tags: furnace, pilot-light

I have a Coleman mobile home furnace and my pilot light keeps going out.  I have replaced the thermocouple twice, cleaned the orfice, replace the gas regulator with a brand new one, and even crawled up on my roof and checked my Flue, my propane tank is fuel so i know its got propane going into it.  This is what keeps happening.  I get the pilot light lit and it will run and warm the mobile home up and then when it shuts down/cools it may kick back on a couple times but then sometime later the pilot goes back out and i cant figure out why and what is going on.  Can you help me give me any ideas on why it keeps doing this?

Comment: Has it worked properly for extended periods of time before?  E.g. did it work fine for years, then stop working at all, and hasn't worked right since you started replacing bits?

Comment: Does this pilot/furnace have a built-in carbon monoxide shutoff?

Answer (score 1):

Something to look at is the pilot flame itself. It is often adjustable by removing a small screw cover marked plt.adj. or something similar. The thermocouple should be fully immersed and the flame should not be *lifting*.

Answer (score 1):

The thermocouple needs to be screwed tightly into it's socket.  And the pilot flame needs to be fairly robust.  If the pilot is weak it will not maintain enough heat to sustain the electric voltage necessary to hold the valve open.